# Accesing properties of derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two derived class that inherit from one base class

```
class Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am base class " << endl:}
       virtual string getName(){ return "base"}
}
class Derived_one : public Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived one " << endl:}
       virtual string getName(){ return "one"}
   private:
  vector<Base*> m;
} 
class Derived_two : public Base{
   public:
      virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived two " << endl:}
      virtual string getName(){ return "two"}
   private:
  vector<string> str;
}
```

The Derived_one class contains a vector of object.
I defined clone function for each object , which means when i push `Derived_two` or `Derived_one` into vector , they will stay as Derived and object slicing wont happen e.g

when i declare print function inside Derived_one class to print the vector e.g

```
void Derived_one::print(){
   for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); i++){
        m[i] -> Greetings()
   }
}
```

It will nicely prints result based on class that was pushed in.( I the last object was Derived_two it will print "I am derived two" and so on.

The problem is , when i want to print the vector of strings inside Derived_two class, when i change `print` method into

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size() ; i++){
   if( m[i] -> getName() == "two" ){
       for( size_t j = 0; j < m[i] -> str.size() ; j++){
           cout << m[i] ->str[j] << endl;
       }
   }
   cout << m[i] ->getName() << endl;
}
```

It throws error

> "Base class does not have member str"

Why is this error happening? The vector should not be inherited from Base class.. Is there a way how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't seen any derivation going  on here.  How is Derived_one or Derived_two derived from Base?

Comment: Think about this: how does the compiler know that `getName()` returning `"two"` automatically guarantees the object has a `str` member? And if there's no guarantee, what is it supposed to do with this code?

Comment: Sorry about that, i didnt notice it , i fixed it , it wont solve problem

Comment: @Jon im quite new to c++ , i have hard time trying to understand this. I have spent few hours googling and so on  but didnt find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cast`: `cast` `Base` objects to `Derived_two` to access `Derived_two` attributes. You will also need to make ̀`str` be `public` or provide a public getter to it (or use `friend`)...

But using `cast` here definitely proves your design is bad. You should use `virtual` functions to have each derived class specialize the `Base` class. Don't use a class name (`getName()`) to discriminate your objects...

As below:

```
class Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am base class " << endl:}
       virtual string getName(){ return "base"}
       virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return NULL; }
};
class Derived_one : public Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived one " << endl:}
       virtual string getName(){ return "one"}
   private:
  vector<Base*> m;
};
class Derived_two : public Base{
   public:
      virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived two " << endl:}
      virtual string getName(){ return "two"}
      virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return &str; }
   private:
  vector<string> str;
};
```

Then do:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size() ; i++){
   if( m[i]->getStr() ){
       // that's a Derived_two object, a vector<string> attribue is available
       for( size_t j = 0; j < m[i]->getStr()->size() ; j++){
           cout << (*(m[i]->getStr()))[j] << endl;
       }
   } else [
       // that's a Derived_one or a Base object, no vector<string> is available
   }

   cout << m[i] ->getName() << endl;
}
```

If you never create any `Base` objects, you can make the class abstract by adding `getStr()`as a pure virtual function:

```
class Base{
       public:
           virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am base class " << endl:}
           virtual string getName(){ return "base"}
           virtual vector<string>* getStr() = 0;
    };
    class Derived_one : public Base{
       public:
           virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived one " << endl:}
           virtual string getName(){ return "one"}
           virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return NULL; }
       private:
      vector<Base*> m;
    };
    class Derived_two : public Base{
       public:
          virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived two " << endl:}
          virtual string getName(){ return "two"}
          virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return &str; }
       private:
      vector<string> str;
    };
```

Comment: Altought i have hard time understanding this , it works , thanks

Comment: At least you learnt what `virtual` means ;-) you'll see it again if you do more C++...

Comment: @ jpo38 yep , btw , the getName() method was also virtual , why didnt it also work? You said about not naming object but it printed right result for the object. Whats the diffrence?

Comment: @trolkura: What do you mean by `why didnt it also work?`. T would have work at runtime, you may discriminate your objects using `getName`. However, this does not allow you to access derived class attributes...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `m[i]` is of type `Base*`, so you need to explicitly downcast from `Base` to `Derived_two` to gain access to members which are only known in `Derived_two`:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size() ; i++){
    if( m[i] -> getName() == "two" ){
        Derived_two * d = static_cast<Derived_two*>(m[i]);
        for( size_t j = 0; j < d -> str.size() ; j++){
            cout << d ->str[j] << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << m[i] ->getName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Now it complains about str vector being private

Comment: OK, you could make Derived_two a friend class of Derived_one, but that stinks.

Comment: `cast` should be avoided when possible. `virtual` functions would produce a better design.